# Golang - Finding the max value of an attribute in an array of objects and return the object

Tags: go

I have this array of objects:

```
[
 {Prop: "something", value: 2},
 {Prop: "something_else", value: 5},
 {Prop: "bla", value: 3}
]
```

I want to find the maximum value over the property "value" and then I want to return the entire object

```
{Prop: "something_else", value: 5}
```

What is the easiest way to do that in golang?

Comment: The most basic way of doing this is by iterating through the array and then store the object in a temporary variable whose `value` attribute is greater than the one already in the temporary variable, and then return the variable

Answer (score 0):

You could just do that:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Something struct {
    Prop  string
    value int
}

func main() {
    somethings := []Something{
        {Prop: "something", value: 2},
        {Prop: "something_else", value: 5},
        {Prop: "bla", value: 3},
    }

    maxObj := somethings[0]

    for _, something := range somethings {
        if something.value > maxObj.value {
            maxObj = something
        }
    }

    fmt.Println(maxObj)
}
```

There is not magic methods/libs